# Vue js class binding in template not working

Tags: vue.js

Having some trouble with this example:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html

I simplified my code for this post:

```
        var classdata = {
            "isActive": false
        }

        Vue.component('app', {
            props: ['intel'],
            template: '<li v-bind:class="{active: this.isActive}" @click="display(intel)"><p>test</p></li>',
            methods: {
                display: function (name) {
                    this.isActive = true;      
                }
            }               
        })

        var app = new Vue({
          el: '#app',
          data: function() {
            return classdata;
          },
        });
```

When I console log in methods, (this.isActive) it reflects the updated state, but it doesnt add the class. I also noticed when I do this
`<li v-bind:class="{active: true}"` it works.

Looking for some clarity!

Answer (score 1):

Try referencing `this` instead of `app`:

```
display: function (name) {
  this.isActive = true;      
}
```

Also, if you're managing `isActive` at the component level, define it in the `data` instead with `props`.

**Edit:**

To manipulate `data` in the child, pass a method through to its `props`:

```js
Vue.component('app', {
  props: ['intel', 'isActive', 'setActive'],
  template: '<li v-bind:class="{active: isActive}" @click="display(intel)"><p>test</p></li>',
  methods: {
    display: function (name) {
        this.setActive(true);
    }
  }               
})

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: function() {
    return classdata;
  },
  methods: {
    setActive: function (val) {
      this.isActive = val
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: when i define isActive in the data and don't reference it in props i get an error message "`Property or method "isActive" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.`" -- -- 
when i try `this.isActive` i get the following error message:
`[Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "isActive"`

Comment: If you can update your question with your updated code, the problem should be easy to spot

Comment: hi tyler, i updated the code but still don't see what i'm missing, any guidance  would be greatly appreciated, i removed the prop and added `this`

Comment: Should just be `active: isActive`. The template is already executed in the context of the component so no need to prefix properties with `this`

Comment: @Phil Good call; I just copy pasted OP's code and missed that.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: @tyler in your example you moved the data into the component, I have the data function inside the main vue instance

Comment: I have the data separate because this is just a snippet of a larger app. Can I use a data function even though it's defined elsewhere? @tyler

Comment: @sn4ke in that case you'll need to pass a function through via `props` that has access to the parent scope.  I've updated my answer to show that.

Comment: @tyler this app is being quite stubborn but this feels much closer, i'm still getting `this.setActive is not a function`

Comment: You need to pass it in via the `:set-active` attribute in your HTML